# What is the absolute vertical accuracy and the relative vertical accuracy of SRTM 1-arc second?

Tags: srtm

When I was looking for the accuracy values for the srtm dem, I found research papers trying to find out these values for its own selected area of study, some of them assume that the absolute value in Africa is around 5.6. I am new to studying remote sensing and GIS, so knowing where exactly to go for trusted information is a bit of challenge.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. There are a number of SRTM products, each with accuracy standards. Some of the datasets contain accuracy metadata. Questions here are expected to show effort toward solving the problem. What sites have you scoured before coming up empty? What search terms did you use that failed to locate an answer?

Comment: Thank you, when I was looking for the accuracy values, I found research papers trying to find out these values for its selected area of study, some of them assume that the absolute value in africa is around 5.6. I am new to studying remote sensing and GIS, so knowing where exactly to go for  trusted information is a bit of challenge.

Comment: Please make sure the question body has your question in it. The title shouldn't be the only part that mentions SRTM.

Answer (score 1):

The **absolute vertical accuracy** of SRTM 1-arc second is equal or less than  ± 16 meters ( at 90% confidence level).SRTM made use of a technique called radar interferometry in which two radar images are taken from slightly different locations. Differences between these images allow for the calculation of surface elevation or change. To get two radar images taken from different locations the SRTM hardware consisted of one radar antenna in the shuttle payload bay and a second radar antenna attached to the end of a mast extended 60 meters (195 feet) out from the shuttle.

The **relative vertical accuracy** is equal or less than ± 10 meters of SRTM 1-arc second.

(According to USGS)